# jquery animate complete function executing before animation is comlete

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove li of ul after animation is completed but
 it makes li remove before completion. Please help me what to do to solve it

```
$('#btnGo').click(function() {

  var $ulCust = $('#divCust ul');

  $ulCust.find('li:first').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: 915
  }, 'slow', function() {
    //this function executes before animation completes
    $('#btnGo').delay(2000).html('Complete'); //this delay is also not working                   
    console.log('complete');
    //$(this).delay(100000).remove();                

  });
 })
});
```

Comment: The delay won't work because `.html()` is not a queue based method....

Comment: *"this function executes before animation completes"* - not possible, it's executed after animation.

Comment: thx for this but main prob executiong animate complete function before animation complete please suggest me if u know answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tL6xpxbf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#btnGo').click(function () {
    var $ulCust = $('#divCust ul');
    $ulCust.find('li:first').animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: 915
        complete: function () {
            $('#btnGo').html('Complete');
        }
    });
});
```